# How to rename all files in subfolder in ubuntu using bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a folder structure like:

```
data
├───sub_data1
│   ├──12_abc.jpg
│   ├──24_abc.jpg
│   └──25_abc.jpg
│
└──sub_data2
    ├──123_abc.jpg
    ├──244_abc.jpg
    └──255_abc.jpg
```

where `data` is the root folder, which contains two subfolders `sub_data1` and `sub_data2`. In these subfolders, I have a lot of jpg files with format `number_abc.jpg`. I want to write one script to change the name from `number_abc.jpg` to `number_xyz.jpg`. The script is written in bash and have one argument to select the path to the root folder (like `data`). How could I do it? I found some examples but I cannot adjust for my case:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
    # separate the file name from its extension
    if [[ $file == *.* ]]; then
      ext="${file##*.}"
      fname="${file%.*}"
      mv "$file" "${fname}_xyz.$ext"
    else
      mv "$file" "${file}_xyz"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You know how you use `mv` instead of `rename` because the syntax for rename is very complicated? This is a case where `rename` can (probably) do what you want!

Comment: I do not understand what you said. I have used above code and it cannot rename my file

Comment: try typing `man rename`

Comment: Does it like `rename 's/abc/xyz/' *`. I used it but nothing change

Comment: I think above command work but I have to cd to sub folder. Could I do it in root folder?

Comment: FYI, it worked now. I used `rename 's/abc/xyz/' */*`

Comment: Sorry. Though I know rename is the correct command I very rarely use it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to do above job (Thanks for the comment Gem Taylor):

```
rename 's/abc/xyz/' */*
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in */*; do fp=$(dirname "$f");  ff=$(basename "$f") ; mv ~/Desktop/files/$fp/$ff ~/Desktop/files/$fp/newName.jpg ; done;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.